# How can I fix: Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

I have been running tests on an emulator for a while successfully for the App I am currently working and all of a sudden they are not running anymore. I have tried with 2 different emulators, I have not tried on a real device. I have also tried to uninstall the app from the emulator.

This happens for all instrument tests on the current app.

Here is the stacktrace from when trying to run the the test:

```
> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Device provider <com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDeviceProvider> failed trying to provide device controller.
Android device (emulator-5554) is not found.
com.google.testing.platform.core.device.DeviceProviderException: ErrorName: UNDETERMINED
NameSpace: com.google.testing.platform
ErrorCode: 3999
Message: Android device (emulator-5554) is not found.
    at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDeviceProvider.provideDevice(DdmlibAndroidDeviceProvider.kt:116)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.DeviceProviderProxy$provideDevice$2.invoke(DeviceProviderProxy.kt:118)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.DeviceProviderProxy$provideDevice$2.invoke(DeviceProviderProxy.kt:117)
    at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
    at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:66)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.DeviceProviderProxy.provideDevice(DeviceProviderProxy.kt:114)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor$execute$deviceController$1.invoke(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:68)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor$execute$deviceController$1.invoke(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:68)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor.runUnlessCancelled(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:105)
    at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor.execute(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:68)
    at com.google.testing.platform.RunnerImpl.run(RunnerImpl.kt:108)
    at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy$run$4.invoke(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:80)
    at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy$run$4.invoke(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:79)
    at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
    at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:66)
    at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy.run(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:79)
    at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt$main$4.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:67)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt:66)
    at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main$default(Main.kt:34)
    at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.google.testing.platform.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:149)
```

Comment: This also happens on a real device

Comment: same problem here, what system and Android Studio version are you using? It seems that manually compiling apk's with gradle and then running it through `adb shell am instrument -w ...` seems to work fine but it's too cumbersome to use

Comment: tried downgrading platform-tools but it doesn't fix it

Comment: I am using Linux and an Android 13 API 33 emulator

Comment: same error on AS Canary build, also I did clean Ubuntu install with stable AS and also same error, so it's not related to any custom config, it's somewhere upstream

Comment: problem should be resolved in newest Android Studio version, it started working for me in Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue using platform-tools 33.0.3 for Linux x86-64, same version on a macOS M1 worked fine. After I tried with version 32.0.0 it worked. You can download it [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r32.0.0-linux.zip).

Comment: I tried downgrading platform-tools, it did not fix my problem

Comment: Can you tell me which version are you using, and to which one you tried downgrading so I can test myself? Also which OS are you using?

Comment: Android Studio: Electric Eel | 2022.1.1, Platform-tools: 32.0.0, OS: Fedora, Linux

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded AS to **Electric Eel | 2022.1.1** (it did not work at the time).  When I tried to run the test after a few days and after switching my computer off, it works fine.

I thinking all I had to do is restart the computer.